# Arrow flip function semi working, almost complete JS

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that allows a user to click a visible div that drops down a "hidden" div/submenu. To the right of the visible div there is an arrow image. In total there are 5 visible divs and 5 arrows. I am needed to have the arrows rotate 180 when the "hidden" div is opened, and rotate back to 0 deg when closed. With the current code written, I am able to select the first arrow image to rotate. If I am to click on the second div, which I would like the second arrow to rotate, the first arrow is getting the script. I would believe to use querySelectorAll, but the console does not pick it up. Any tips are always greatly appreciated!

```
//
const questionBox = document.getElementsByClassName("question__container");
const arrows = document.querySelector(".question__container--img");

[...questionBox].forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(
      ".options__container"
    );
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
    if (subMenu.classList.contains("open")) {
      arrows.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    } else {
      arrows.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    }
  })
);
//
```

[image: second div is open, yet first arrow gets the function call]

Comment: The easiest to use way (since it's just rotation) would be to add the rotation to a class 'open' in CSS, and just use a spread operator on the questionBox list, making the `ith` arrow (the one clicked) update. E.G. [...questionBox, questionBox[i].addClass('open') If you post a code snippet, I'll show you in the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on your current logic, here's what you could do.

- Get all arrows with `querySelectorAll`
- Create a function `collapseAllArrows` that basically loops through all arrows and collapses them.
- When any of the div element is clicked and the `subMenu` for that element is toggled to `open` then call the `collapseAllArrows` function to collapse all expanded arrows.
- The find the arrow for the clicked div element and expand it.

Your code should look something like this

```js
const questionBox = document.getElementsByClassName("question__container");
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".question__container--img");

const collapseAllArrows = () => {
  arrows.forEach(arrow => arrow.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";)
}

[...questionBox].forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(
      ".options__container"
    );

    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");

    if (subMenu.classList.contains("open")) {
      collapseAllArrows();
      const currentArrow = el.querySelector(".question__container--img");
      currentArrow.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
    }
  })
);
```